# How do I can take the Pitest coverage report in Sonarqube instead of JaCoco?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, pitest

I use Sonarqube 6.7.1 and the project in Gradle 3.0.

I am generating Pitest report successfully, Sonarqube take Pitest xml report and creating the issues successfully too.
I need replace the jaCoco project coverage to Pitest line coverage because the project have tests with powermock and the jaCoco coverage isn't representative.

If do you have any suggestion, is accepted.

Thanks.